# Should I ask potential recommenders whether they know someone?

Tags: recommendation-letter

Let's say someone is applying for a PhD or postdoc position (or a number of such positions), and needs to decide who should write a recommendation letter. Assume that two letters are needed, but the person has four professors to choose from. All four professors say that they are comfortable with writing a strong letter.

The applicant feels that all else equal, potential hirers give more weight to letters from people they know. Is it ok for the applicant to ask their professors whether they know a potential hirer, so that recommendation letters can be channelled accordingly?

Comment: See: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/97316/is-it-appropriate-to-ask-professors-at-which-schools-their-recommendation-letter